# Fantasy movies; Harryhausen-esque, with warriors who magically generate from a mural

Tags: identify-this-movie, fantasy

I was wondering if someone can help me identify a movie I saw from my childhood.  It was a fantasy movie along the lines of a Harryhausen movie.  A wizard or king has a young man to go on a journey for something, I cant remember what the goal was.

He is given some warriors created magically from a mural painted on the wall of a dark room or hall.  Along the journey some of his men fall into some quicksand. Then their skeletons float to the top.  That is really all I remember from the movie.  Can you help me identify the name of the movie.

Comment: Welcome! Seeing as we don't know whether you're 22 or 82, could you tell us when your "childhood" was, so that we can get an idea of when the film came out? Thanks!

Comment: [Krull](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrZvCFHSUOkhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrZvCFHSUOk)?

Comment: Or the infamous [Skeletons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pF_Fi7x93PY) scene from Jason and the Argonauts

Comment: @BamfTheNightAway genre tags are not for identification questions. They are for questions having to do with said genre.

Answer (score 3):

I am quite sure you are you are looking for [The magic sword](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056211/) from 1962.

> George (Gary Lockwood) is the foster son of Sybil (Estelle Winwood), an elderly sorceress. She brought him up after his "royal parents died of the plague" in his infancy. He has fallen in love at first sight with Princess Helene (Anne Helm).
>
> She is kidnapped by the wizard Lodac (Basil Rathbone), who brazenly informs her father that he intends to feed her to his pet dragon in seven days, revenge for the death of his sister at the same age as Helene is now: 18. George wants to go on a quest to liberate his lady love, but Sybil believes he is too young (he is 20). She tries to distract the youth by showing him a magic sword, a steed, an invulnerable suit of armour, and six magically frozen knights he will command when he turns 21. The impatient George, however, tricks Sybil and locks her in a cellar, then leaves with the magical implements and revived company of knights....
> [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_Sword_%281962_film%29) in the wikipedia article

It has the scenes you describe and you can find the full movie on youtube.

The warriors from painting scene is at 17:20

the skeleton scene is at 38:00. (a single warrior and swamp/boiling water not quicksand)

Comment: @richard: that was an easy one for me, altough it is a trashy movie, i loved it as child and watched it several times ;)

Comment: I'm kicking myself for not getting it. I've even seen it quite recently.

Comment: Estelle Winwood was hilarious in "Murder by Death"

Comment: @Pat, consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234).